# Where can I find more recipe scraps?

Tags: fiz

I've found a recipe scrap! I don't know how I did it, but I appear to have one. A recipe scrap reveals part of a new recipe and the tip that pops up states that I can guess the rest to work out the recipe or find the remaining scraps.

What other actions can result in me finding more recipe scraps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find scraps by tapping on the mouse that runs around the garage as you brew.  You can also learn recipes by completing events.